# `setDoc` write to Firestore from TypeScript Functions messes up directory structure on `npm run build`

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Transpiling TypeScript creates a new, incorrect directory structure when a Firebase Function writes to Firestore with `setDoc` or `updateDoc`.

This code transpiles and runs correctly:

*index.ts*

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
export const MakeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    try {
      const original = snap.data().original;
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snap.ref.set({ uppercase }, { merge: true }); // writes to the same document
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error); // emulator always throws an "unhandled error": "Your function timed out after ~60s."
      return 0;
    }
  });
```

The first time the function is transpiled in a new directory the transpiler makes this directory structure:

```
myproject
├── environments
│   └── environment.ts
├── functions
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
```

That directory structure is correct. The `main` in `package.json` is

```
lib/index.js
```

Let's change the code a little and use `setDoc` to write to a different directory in Firestore:

*index.ts*

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export const MakeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    try {
      const original = snap.data().original;
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

      return setDoc(
        doc(firestore, 'AnotherCollection', context.params.docId),
        { uppercase }, { merge: true }
      );

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error); // emulator always throws an "unhandled error": "Your function timed out after ~60s."
      return 0;
    }
  });
```

I transpile the function with `npm run build` in the `functions` directory. The directory structure changes to:

```
myproject
├── environments
│   └── environment.ts
├── functions
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── environments
│   │   │   ├── environment.js
│   │   │   └── environment.js.map
│   │   ├── functions
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       ├── index.js
│   │   │       ├── index.js.map
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
```

The transpiler added three new directories and four new files. It's exposing my `apiKey` and other credentials. To make the new function run I changed `main` to

```js
lib/functions/src/index.js
```

Now the new code runs but it won't write to Firestore. I'm getting `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` errors. Here's my rules:

*firestore-rules*

```
rules_version = "2";
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Don't worry, those rules are for the emulator, not for production.

A couple more weird things. Visual Studio Code shows a single directory `functions/src`, not two, nested directories. (MacOS shows two nested directories.)

I can deploy the new function to Cloud Functions with `firebase deploy` but `gcloud functions deploy` won't deploy the function. It throws an error that it can't find `index.js`:

```
lib/functions/src/index.js does not exist;
```

What is going on here??? To test this I spun up four new Firebase Functions directories. I tried different functions. It happens every time I use `setDoc` or `updateDoc`, and doesn't happen if the code doesn't include `setDoc` or `updateDoc`.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

*tsconfig.json*

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why you use library meant to be used in browser? `"firebase/firestore/lite"` is meant to be used in SSR apps rendered in node.js.

Comment: Still, using Firebase SDK meant to be used in browser in most cases scenario you won't be able to `setDoc()` because of lack of authentication. Unless you don't want to have a secured database and want everyone to be able to change everything in it.

Comment: You have a bunch of unrelated complaints in this post so it's hard to know what your question really is.  Also you changed the code way more than "a little" between the first and second code samples.  I strongly suggest narrowing this down to something specific.  If you have different issues, please post them separately using an minimal code that duplicates a specific problem.   Note that gcloud can not (and will never) deploy in the same way as the FIrebase CLI. They are completely different tools not related to each other, so I suggest leaving that out of the problem statement for now.

Comment: It also seems you are trying to use the Firestore web client SDK in Cloud Functions, which is not really the right thing to do.  You should use the Admin SDK in Cloud Functions.  That's what you're already using "for free" when you get a document snapshot in the function handler in your first sample when you use the provided document snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Doug Stevenson! What I'm reading in your comment is that Firebase Cloud Functions can't use the Firebase 9 syntax `setDoc` and `updateDoc` for Firestore, and `uploadString` etc. for Storage. We have to use the old school Firebase syntax, like this:

*index.js*

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

export const MakeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{docId}').onCreate(async (snap: any, context: any) => {
    try {
        const original = snap.data().original;
        const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
        await admin.firestore().collection('AnotherCollection').add({uppercase: uppercase});
        return uppercase;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error); // emulator always throws an "unhandled error": "Your function timed out after ~60s."
        return 0;
    }
});
```

That transpiled without creating new directories or files, and ran without a problem.